# Can not dissmiss progress default progress dialog andorid

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to `Android` and learning it on my own. I am trying to implement android's default `ProgressDialog`, but the problem is, it is not dismissing when i call `dismiss()` method in my network response.

```
private void loadData() {
//        rooms.clear();
        final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progress.show(getContext(),"Loading..","Please wait");
        progress.show();    
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Api.getAllPost, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                progress.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Room room = new Gson().fromJson(object.toString(),Room.class);
//                        Toast.makeText(context, "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        rooms.add(room);
                    }
                    roomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Server error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

I tried other solution in this site but did not worked. please someone help me.

Comment: Dismiss the ProgressBar when it adds data into room.

Comment: treid that but no help. and my response code is working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `ProgressDialog` since it is deprecated now. But for your solution try replacing your code:

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progress.show(getContext(),"Loading..","Please wait");
progress.show();
```

By below code:

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
progress.setTitle("Loading..");
progress.setMessage("Please wait");
progress.setCancelable(false);
progress.show();
```

it should work :)